# Extending 2 arrays depending on a value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two example arrays:

```
$array1 = array(
    0 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234),
    1 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 234),
    2 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234),
    3 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 234),
    4 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234),
    5 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 898),
    6 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234),
    7 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 234),
    8 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234),
    9 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 898)
);

$array2 = array(
    0 => array("b" => '234', "c" => "Herr"),
    1 => array("b" => '898', "c" => "Frau"),
);
```

Array 1 should be extended by c, depending on the value in b, which is present in both arrays. Finally, array 1 should look like this:

```
$array3 = array(
    0 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    1 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    2 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    3 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    4 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    5 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 898, "c" => "Frau"),
    6 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    7 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    8 => array("a" => '123', "b" => 234, "c" => "Herr"),
    9 => array("a" => 'abs', "b" => 898, "c" => "Frau")
);
```

Are there already simple ways to realize this in PHP7.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an iteration over `$array1` using [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php). In `use()` scope pass the filter array prepared (`['234' => 'Herr', '898' => 'Frau']`) from `$array2`. In every cycle of the iteration get value from `$filter` array by the index value of `b` and set it to `$array1`'s `c` index. **Example**:

```
$filter = array_column($array2, 'c', 'b');
array_walk($array1, function(&$val) use ($filter) { 
    $val['c'] = $filter[$val['b']]; 
});
print_r($array1);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/ltPrK).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be a loop through `foreach`, create an array that contains all the `b` indexes in `$array2` by using `array_column()`. Then use `array_search()` on that column, and look for the index `b` of the current iteration of `$array1` - that key (from `$array2`) will tell you which index to choose. Fetch the value and append it to the temporary array, then append the temporary array into `$array3`.

```
$array3 = array();
$b_values = array_column($array2, "b");

foreach ($array1 as $v) {
    $temp = $v;
    $key_2 = array_search($v['b'], $b_values);
    $temp['c']  = $array2[$key_2]['c'];
    $array3[] = $temp;
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/lZHKS